# Type of Indexing suitable for a view

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a view created as follows :-

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwNumberOfEditsForTimeSheets]
AS
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT TimeSheetId, COUNT(TimeSheetId) AS NumberOfEdits
FROM     dbo.TimeSheetLogs AS tsl
WHERE  (StatusId = 27)
GROUP BY TimeSheetId
ORDER BY TimeSheetId
```

It probably has about 1,00,000 entries now and would increase by around 500 to 1000 each day.

Which type of indexing would be best for this type of view?

Thanks

Comment: For starters, get rid of the `TOP 100 PERCENT / ORDER BY`. The optimizer simplifies this meaningless part of the query away, and it gives false promises about sort order when you select without order by.

Comment: What kind of **queries** do you get against this view?

Comment: @marc_s I use select queries to fetch all the records of a specified timesheets and display how many times they are edited.
i have a status part in my entry if that is set to inactive i have a different new entry which is the active entry and this way there can be multiple entry for particular TimeSheetId.

Comment: And how often do you submit edits to the time sheet table, compared to how often you run selects against the view? As I hinted in my answer, indexed views aren't free.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It is ran each time user pulls up that RazorView. So guess if there are 500 entries a day we would pull up that RazorView 1000 time. Double because that many entries would be made and the partial would get refreshed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could in fact use an indexed view here

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwNumberOfEditsForTimeSheets]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT TimeSheetId,
         COUNT_BIG(*) AS NumberOfEdits
  FROM   dbo.TimeSheetLogs AS tsl
  WHERE  ( StatusId = 27 )
  GROUP  BY TimeSheetId

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX
  ON [dbo].[vwNumberOfEditsForTimeSheets](TimeSheetId)
```

Dependant on edition you might need to use the `NOEXPAND` hint to get it to be used.

If you don't want to use an indexed view then the optimum index on the base table to support that `SELECT` query would be

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX ON  dbo.TimeSheetLogs(StatusId, TimeSheetId)
```

to alllow the lookup by `StatusId` with matching rows ordered by `TimeSheetId` and thus easily grouped and counted by a stream aggregate.

Comment: What is the need to use COUNT_BIG?

Comment: @user1960365 - This is one of many restrictions on indexed views that you can't use `COUNT` but must use `COUNT_BIG`, They are basically the same except the second one supports larger numbers of rows and so returns `bigint` rather than `int`

Comment: So the second one is using more resources then it should be.So don't you think Count would be a better option in that case?

Comment: @user1960365 -  `bigint` takes 8 bytes per row in the index and `int` only 4 so yes it might be good if `COUNT` was allowed but it isn't so the question is moot.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Good point if they only care about `StatusId = 27`

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes we would just care about the StatusId = 27. So then how should the filtered index approach be used?

Comment: @user1960365 - The index definition for that is `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX2 ON  dbo.TimeSheetLogs( TimeSheetId) WHERE  (StatusId = 27)` it is a cut down version of the second suggestion in my answer as it doesn't store the `StatusId` values or rows for StatusIds that you aren't interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Note that indexed views make some of your queries faster, but they require more maintenance when you are updating (insert, update, delete, merge) the base table. You really should check if this view is worth what you pay for it by performing tests against your full workload, not just the selects against the view.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwNumberOfEditsForTimeSheets]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT TimeSheetId, COUNT_BIG(*) AS NumberOfEdits
    FROM dbo.TimeSheetLogs AS tsl
    WHERE (StatusId = 27)
    GROUP BY TimeSheetId;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX TSId 
  ON dbo.vwNumberOfEditsForTimeSheets(TimeSheetId);
GO
```

If you are on standard edition, you may have to use the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint to make use of the view.

Comment: When should this WITH (NOEXPAND) be used.
I am using SQLSERVER2012 Express.
Can you explain that to me.

Comment: @user1960365 - You will need the hint then otherwise the indexed view will not be used and it will still access the base table instead. Example syntax `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vwNumberOfEditsForTimeSheets] WITH (NOEXPAND)`. Only on Enterprise Edition Engine (includes developer edition) is this not required.